# Recursive function doesn't return created string

Tags: string, python-3.x, knapsack-problem

I am new at Python, so maybe it can be a silly question.

I've implemented a simple recursive knapsack solution which returns a bit sequence eventually. But sometimes it does not return sequence which is generated. Here is my code and its results for different inputs.

```
def knapsackRecursive(items, maxNum, bestResponse):
    print('items=' + str(items) + ', maxNum=' + str(maxNum))
    referenceIndex = 0
    editableMaxNum = maxNum
    if editableMaxNum == 0:
        bestResponse = '0'
    else:
        for i in reversed(items):
            item = int(i)
            if editableMaxNum >= item:
                if referenceIndex == 0:
                    referenceIndex = items.index(str(item))
                editableMaxNum -= item
                bestResponse = '1' + bestResponse
            else:
                bestResponse = '0' + bestResponse
        if editableMaxNum != 0:
            bestResponse = ''
            if referenceIndex != 0:
                for k in range(0, len(items) - referenceIndex):
                    bestResponse = '0' + bestResponse

                knapsackRecursive(items[:referenceIndex], maxNum, bestResponse)
            else:
                bestResponse = '0'

    print('bestResponse=' + str(bestResponse))
    return bestResponse
```

`Items` are constants which are ['1', '2', '4', '10', '20', '40', '63', '105']. Also initial `bestResponse` is empty string.

if I set `maxNum` as 41, output is:

```
items=['1', '2', '4', '10', '20', '40', '63', '105'], maxNum=41
bestResponse=10000100
```

But if I set `maxNum` as 71, output is:

```
items=['1', '2', '4', '10', '20', '40', '63', '105'], maxNum=71
items=['1', '2', '4', '10', '20', '40'], maxNum=71
bestResponse=10011100
bestResponse=00
```

Why does `bestResponse` output printed twice for input 71? And although first print is right, why does function returns the second result which is wrong?

**EDIT**

I have changed `knapsackRecursive(items[:referenceIndex], maxNum, bestResponse)` as `return knapsackRecursive(items[:referenceIndex], maxNum, bestResponse)`. It seems resolved. Obviously I made a mistake when using recursive. But still I couldn't understand that why does function returns the result of first call instead of the second call which is expected to generate the right response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
best_response = knapsackRecursive(items[:referenceIndex], maxNum, bestResponse)
```

instead of

```
knapsackRecursive(items[:referenceIndex], maxNum, bestResponse)
```